# How to make efficient database listener application? (.NET Core)

Tags: c#, database, .net-core, iis, model-view-controller

I'm trying to do a database listener application. My goal is listen to Oracle Database table called "**PB_TRANSACTION**". If new record has inserted into Oracle table, it would execute **"dep_OnChange"** event handler and insert into SQL Server database table.

I'm doing on .NET Core web application. But my code currently doesn't meet my requirements.

Here's my questions:

- My app only works when webpage opened (example: https://localhost:44326/) and if i reload webpage my code is no longer working. I don't want to open webpages on browser. I expect background process. When i reload page, this error comes in as shown below
  [image: When i reload page, this error comes in]
- .NET CORE Web Api is correct way to do it? Because i want to host my app on IIS.

Here's my Startup.cs code:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using GetNotificationsfromDB.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace GetNotificationsfromDB
{
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddRazorPages();
        //services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        //app.UseStaticFiles();
        
        app.UseRouting();

        //app.UseAuthorization();
        
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
        
        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            //Create a connection to Oracle         
            string conString = "User Id=;Password=;" +

            //How to connect to an Oracle DB without SQL*Net configuration file
            //  also known as tnsnames.ora.
            //"Data Source=orclpdb";
            "Data Source=eoffice";

            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString);
            OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();

            OracleDependency dep = null;

            try
            {
                OracleConfiguration.OracleDataSources.Add("eoffice", "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVICE_NAME = eoffice)))");

                if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                cmd.CommandText = "select * from PB_TRANSACTION";

                cmd.AddRowid = true;
                dep = new OracleDependency(cmd);
                cmd.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

                dep.OnChange += new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OnChangeEventHandler(dep_OnChange);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Get stack trace for the exception with source file information
                var st = new StackTrace(ex, true);
                // Get the top stack frame
                var frame = st.GetFrame(0);
                // Get the line number from the stack frame
                var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR: " + ex.Message + " Line:" + line);
                //await context.Response.WriteAsync("ERROR:");
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Dispose();
            }

            void dep_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs eventArgs)
            {
                //Code Executed
                using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(conString))
                {
                    using (OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            Transaction LastTransaction = new Transaction();

                            cmd.CommandText = "select * from (select * from pb_transaction order by id desc) x where ROWNUM <= :lastrecord";
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("lastrecord", 1);
                            con.Open();
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            using (OracleDataReader oReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                while (oReader.Read())
                                {
                                    LastTransaction.Id = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["ID"]);
                                    LastTransaction.type = oReader["TYPE"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.account = oReader["ACCOUNT"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.journal_id = oReader["JOURNAL_ID"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.amount = Convert.ToDouble(oReader["AMOUNT"]);
                                    LastTransaction.currency = oReader["CURRENCY"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.posted_date = oReader["POSTED_DATE"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.statement_date = oReader["STATEMENT_DATE"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.description = oReader["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.pnr = oReader["PNR"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.pnr_approved = Convert.ToInt32(oReader["PNR_APPROVED"]);
                                    LastTransaction.jid = oReader["JID"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.user_id = oReader["USER_ID"].ToString();
                                    LastTransaction.inserted_date = oReader["INSERTED_DATE"].ToString();


                                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data source=SAMBUUYONDON; Database=TestEnviroment;User Id=sa;Password=root");

                                    //Duplicate record байгаа хэсгийг шалгах
                                    SqlCommand check_id = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [PB_TRANSACTION] WHERE ([ID] = @id)", conn);
                                    check_id.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", LastTransaction.Id);
                                    conn.Open();
                                    int RecordExist = (int)check_id.ExecuteScalar();

                                    if (RecordExist > 0)
                                    {
                                        
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        //INSERT
                                        SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand("insert into PB_TRANSACTION (ID,TYPE, ACCOUNT, JOURNAL_ID, AMOUNT, CURRENCY, POSTED_DATE, STATEMENT_DATE, DESCRIPTION, PNR, PNR_APPROVED, JID, USER_ID, INSERTED_DATE) values(@id,@type,@account,@journalid, @amount,@currency,@posteddate,@statementdate,@description,@pnr,@pnrapproved,@jid,@userid,@inserteddate);", conn);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", LastTransaction.Id);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", LastTransaction.type);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account", LastTransaction.account);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@journalid", LastTransaction.journal_id);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", LastTransaction.amount);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currency", LastTransaction.currency);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@posteddate", LastTransaction.posted_date);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@statementdate", LastTransaction.statement_date);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", LastTransaction.description);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnr", LastTransaction.pnr);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnrapproved", LastTransaction.pnr_approved);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jid", LastTransaction.jid);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", LastTransaction.user_id);
                                        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inserteddate", LastTransaction.inserted_date);
                                        scmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                    conn.Close();
                                }
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"D:\MIAT\ONLINE_BOOKING\errorlog.txt"))
                            {
                                writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });          
    }
}
}
```

My Transaction.cs model:

```
using System;

namespace GetNotificationsfromDB.Models
{
    public class Transaction
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string account { get; set; }
    public string journal_id { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string posted_date { get; set; }
    public string statement_date { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string pnr { get; set; }
    public int pnr_approved { get; set; }
    public string jid { get; set; }
    public string user_id { get; set; }
    public string inserted_date { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Run` defines middleware, which runs on each request. What you want is a hosted service; see `BackgroundService`.